# Как изменить стейт слайса из экшена другого слайса в redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

У меня `React` приложение на `typeScript`. Я использую `redux-toolkit`. Перешел я на него недавно, ранее пользовался обычным редаксом.

У меня есть два слайса, первый `user` - он хранит в себе токен и инфу о пользователе. У него также есть два экшена, которые удаляют токен и пользователя из стейта. Второй слайс хранит объект ошибок API. Когда при каком-то запросе приходит от сервера сообщение об ошибке, то оно сразу же отправляется в стейт слайса `errors`. Для этого в этом слайсе есть экшен `addNewError`.

Но возникла ситуация, когда при коде ошибки 12 мне надо удалить токен и пользователя. Проверка когда ошибки происходит в экшене `addNewError` перед тем как сохранить эту ошибку в стейт. Ведь если ошибка имеет код 12, то ее не нужно сохранять в стейт.

Но я не понимаю как вызвать экшены удаления токена и юзера из экшена `addNewError`. Ведь это совершенно другой слайс.

Вот коды моих слайсов:

```
UserSlice
```

```typescript
import UserStorage from "../../localStorage/userStorage";
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { RootState } from "../../store";
import { User } from "./user";


interface UserState {
    token: string | null
    user: User | null
    isLogInLoading: boolean
}

const initialState: UserState = {
    token: UserStorage.getToken(),
    user: UserStorage.getUser(),
    isLogInLoading: false
}

export const UserSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setToken: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
            state.token = action.payload
            UserStorage.setToken(action.payload)
        },
        setUser: (state, action: PayloadAction<User>) => {
            state.user = action.payload
            UserStorage.setUser(action.payload)
        },
        clearToken: (state) => {
            state.token = null
            UserStorage.removeToken()
        },
        clearUser: (state) => {
            state.user = null
            UserStorage.removeUser()
        },
        setLogInLoading: (state, action: PayloadAction<boolean>) => {
            state.isLogInLoading = action.payload
        }
    }
})

export default UserSlice.reducer

export const { setToken, setUser, clearToken, clearUser, setLogInLoading } = UserSlice.actions

export const selectToken = (state: RootState) => state.user.token
```

```
ErrorsSlice
```

```typescript
import { ApiError, ApiWarning } from "../apiResponseModels";
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

interface ErrorState {
    apiError: ApiError | null
    warningsChannel: ApiWarning[]
}

const initialState: ErrorState = {
    apiError: null,
    warningsChannel: []
}

const warningTypeErrorCodes: number[] = [
    // Add all error codes which has warning only type
]

export const ErrorSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'errors',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        addNewError: (state, action: PayloadAction<ApiError>) => {
            const errorObj = action.payload
            if (errorObj.code === 12) {
                // здесь надо вызвать экшены clearToken и clearUser, которые находятся в другом слайсе user
            }
            else if (warningTypeErrorCodes.includes(errorObj.code)) {
                const warningObj = {
                    ...errorObj,
                    fired: false,
                    localId: uuidv4()
                }
                state.warningsChannel = [warningObj, ...state.warningsChannel]
            } else {
                state.apiError = errorObj
            }
        },
        removeError: (state) => {
            state.apiError = null
        },
        deleteOneWarning: (state, action: PayloadAction<ApiWarning>) => {
            const { localId } = action.payload

            const indexToRemove = state.warningsChannel.findIndex(
                (warning) => warning.localId === localId
            )

            if (indexToRemove !== -1) {
                state.warningsChannel = [
                    ...state.warningsChannel.slice(0, indexToRemove),
                    ...state.warningsChannel.slice(indexToRemove + 1),
                ]
            }
        },
        clearAllWarnings: (state) => {
            state.warningsChannel = []
        }
    }
})

export default ErrorSlice.reducer

export const { addNewError, removeError, deleteOneWarning, clearAllWarnings } = ErrorSlice.actions
```

Comment: Импортируйте `clearToken` и `clearUser` в слайс `ErrorSlice` и вызовите там, где нужно.

Comment: @meine каким образом?